# Parent Page's keyDown event fires even after handled in the user control

Tags: uwp

I have an IndexPage with CoreWindow_KeyDown event. It fires when I press a key. That's right. If I press a key on a user control which contains PreviewKeyDown/KeyDown event, the indexpage's  CoreWindow_KeyDown event also fires along with the user control's PreviewKeyDown/KeyDown event.

```
UserControl_PreviewKeyDown, e.Handled = true
UserControl_KeyDown, e.Handled = true
```

How to prevent the IndexPage from firing the CoreWindow_KeyDown event, if it handled by a user control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Parent Page's keyDown event fires even after handled in the user control

It's by design, set e.Handled as true for `UserControl_PreviewKeyDown` will not disable the route event bubble to `CoreWindow`.

For your requirement,  due to the trigger condition of `PreviewKeyDown` is that the control need to be focused, we could declare bool property and set it as true when the control is focused.  And use this bool property to disable process logic within `CoreWindow_KeyDown` event.

```
private void CoreWindow_KeyDown(Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow sender, Windows.UI.Core.KeyEventArgs args)
{
    if (!_isFocus)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("---------!_isFocus-----------");
    }
    else
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("---------_isFocus-----------");
    }
}

private bool _isFocus;
private void MyCC_GettingFocus(UIElement sender, GettingFocusEventArgs args)
{
    _isFocus = true;
}

private void MyCC_LosingFocus(UIElement sender, LosingFocusEventArgs args)
{
    _isFocus = false;
}
```